# Jupyter Notebook not recognizing packages in the newly added kernals

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have anaconda base environment and 1 other environment where i have tensorflow installed which i am trying to import in my jupyter notebook after changing the kernel.

i installed jupyter notebook in my conda base environment using the following command:

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub`
and by simply doing:
`pip install jupyter`

after that i added my new environment with tensorflow and some other additional packages with this command:
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name env_cod --display-name "Python (env_cod)"`

So now i launch jupyter notebook by simple (jupyter-notebook) in the desired directory and i also tried launching jupyter-notebook after activating the env_cod environment from terminal. But still i am not able to import tensorflow in my jupyter notebook after changing the kernal by selecting from the kernel tab also when i create new jupyter notebook by selecting env_cod environment i am not able to import tensorflow and get this error : 
`no module named tensorflow`

I already tried uninstalling and installing jupyter in my both base and env_cod environment.

Also there is nothing wrong with my env_cod environment and tensorflow is working perfectly fine along with other packages when i run my scripts through PyCharm after selecting env_cod environment. The Problem is Only with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Check your interpreter path in the notebook via `import sys; print(sys.executable)`.  If it does not point to your new environment, that is the issue.

Comment: Yeah it still points to the base environment as expected even after changing the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by editing the .jason file and providing the right path to the environment executable.

Edit.

all i did was to go into `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels`
and you will find all the kernels which you added into Jupyter Notebook.
Now just go to folder which is not loading the correct Python Executable and you will find **kernel.json** file in that folder.
Open that file

```
{
 "argv": [
  "D:\\Path\\To\\Correct\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "ENV_NAME",
 "language": "python"
}
```

For some reason the path to python executable was of my Base Python Environment so i changed it to my Virtual Environment's Python Executable Path and after that it loads the correct environment in my Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: could you be more specific please?

Comment: Answer Edited for explanation hope it helps.

Comment: hello! can you provide an example of your correct environment path python executable?
I believe I am having the same issue and changed my path from C:\\Users\\name\\miniconda3\\python.exe to C:\\Users\\name\\miniconda3\\envs\\env_name\\python.exe and its not liking it!